# Do Windows versions matter when doing browser testing?

Tags: javascript, windows, testing, browser, cross-browser

I'm testing IE7, IE8, Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

It would be pretty less boring if you guys told me that I don't need to test for XP, Vista and 7, since there's no difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences to do with security, in particular what varieties of Windows authentication (NTLM and Kerberos over HTTP) are acceptable.

Also of course each Windows version has a different theme, which will affect what form elements look like and may trip you up if you were relying on the same pixel size of a scrollbar or something like that (a bad thing to do anyway).

Other than that, no, they're pretty much the same.

Comment: Are you sure? A friend of mine just mentioned he had some JS differences between IE7 on Vista and on XP.

Comment: There's no difference in the JScript language itself, no, both use the same jscript version/implementation. There may be differences visible *from* script, such as various ActiveX controls being blocked by default, but nothing you shouldn't already be coping with in XP.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million. You just saved me... well, 66% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences in the same Browser Version run on different Windows OS. So if you test your site in IE* on Windows Vista, it should work in XP and 7, too. And also the other ways around. But I would use at least Windows Vista, because the IE9 is coming soon, and it won't run on XP.

Answer (score 1):

I would also test on the different operating systems due to the way fonts may render as your layout could be impacted. Here's a site with a reference of some differences.

http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/res_fonts.htm

Functionality will likely not be impacted, but if you are going to have users that have those versions of the operating system you need to test on them.

Comment: What about JS, is it the same?

Comment: I'm not aware of any javascript differences across versions of windows.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million. You just saved me... well, 66% of the time.